# Python UML Diagrams

Tags: python, uml

I am creating a UML diagram for a Python class.

Is it standard to include the public/private/protected tags when doing UMLs for Python programs?  For instance:

```
-n: int
+name_of_shop: str
```

My current program has every variable and function as public, since I didn't want my variables to start with single (_) or double (__) underscores. If the variables aren't accessed outside the function, is it standard for every variable to begin with the double underscore?

Comment: [This link](/questions/42481269/custom-uml-generator) might help; it should have turned up in your research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Python *standard* vis-a-vis UML.  There are conventions in both paradigms.  How you resolve them is up to you and your consumers, i.e., whomever is evaluating your work.

Python itself imposes very few standards beyond the necessity of the language syntax.  Remember our over-arching precept: "A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds".  You can see the [coding guidelines](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (often referred to as The PEP-8 Coding Standard").

That said, I have two basic notes:

1. Yes, internal variables generally begin with an underscore.
2. You need to take up the readability and propriety with your instructor and/or grader.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is whether to use underscore, PEP8 has it
[Descriptive: Naming Styles](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id36)
Basically says

- _single underscore prefix for weak "internal use" indicator
- single_ underscore suffix for avoiding conflicts with keyword
- __double underscore prefix for mangles
- __ double__ underscore on both end for magic that should not be invented.